# alias a subselect and where

Tags: mysql, sql

The following :

```
select 
    `restaurants`.*, 
    ST_Distance_Sphere(point(longitude, latitude), point(12.345600, -12.345600)) as distance 
from `restaurants` 
where `distance` <= `delivery_max_range`
```

will return a `Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'`.

A little search revealed a solution as :

```
select 
    `restaurants`.*, 
from `restaurants` 
where 
    ST_Distance_Sphere(point(longitude, latitude`), point(12.345600, -12.345600)) <= `delivery_max_range`
```

Which does work indeed, but I do need that computed `distance` column alias since I want to print it to the end user.

I came up with the following :

```
select 
    `restaurants`.*, 
    (ST_Distance_Sphere(point(longitude, latitude), point(12.345600, -12.345600))) as `distance` 
from `restaurants` 
where 
    ST_Distance_Sphere(point(longitude, latitude`), point(12.345600, -12.345600)) <= `delivery_max_range`
```

which looks as ugly as it probably is. Is there a better way of doing this? I'm concerned about the double distance calculation from the mysql engine. There are thousands of restaurants.

Use case:
I want to filter restaurants that can (`delivery_max_range`) deliver to my home (lng=12.345600, lat=-12.345600). I want to show the `distance` to each restaurant that meet that criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL extends the use of the `HAVING` clause, so it can be used in non-aggregation queries.  That works in this case:

```
select r.*, 
       ST_Distance_Sphere(point(longitude, latitude), point(12.345600, -12.345600)) as distance 
from restaurants r
having`distance <= delivery_max_range;
```

Note:  There is no need to use backticks everywhere.